# Calculating means of values for subgroups of keys in python dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary which looks like this:

```
cq={'A1_B2M_01':2.04, 'A2_B2M_01':2.58, 'A3_B2M_01':2.80, 'B1_B2M_02':5.00, 
'B2_B2M_02':4.30, 'B2_B2M_02':2.40 etc.}
```

I need to calculate mean of triplets, where the keys[2:] agree. So, I would ideally like to get another dictionary which will be:

```
new={'_B2M_01': 2.47, '_B2M_02': 3.9}
```

The data is/should be in triplets so in theory I could just get the means of the consecutive values, but first of all, I have it in a dictionary so the keys/values will likely get reordered, besides I'd rather stick to the names, as a quality check for the triplets assigned to names (I will later add a bit showing error message when there will be more than three per group). 
I've tried creating a dictionary where the keys would be _B2M_01 and _B2M_02 and then loop through the original dictionary to first append all the values that are assigned to these groups of keys so I could later calculate an average, but I am getting errors even in the first step and anyway, I am not sure if this is the most effective way to do this...

```
cq={'A1_B2M_01':2.4, 'A2_B2M_01':5, 'A3_B2M_01':4, 'B1_B2M_02':3, 'B2_B2M_02':7, 'B3_B2M_02':6}
trips=set([x[2:] for x in cq.keys()])
new={}
for each in trips:
    for k,v in cq.iteritems():
        if k[2:]==each:
            new[each].append(v)

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#28>", line 4, in <module>
    new[each].append(v)
KeyError: '_B2M_01'
```

I would be very grateful for any suggestions. It seems like a fairly easy operation but I got stuck.

An alternative result which would be even better would be to get a dictionary which contains all the names used as in cq, but with values being the means of the group. So the end result would be:

```
final={'A1_B2M_01':2.47, 'A2_B2M_01':2.47, 'A3_B2M_01':2.47, 'B1_B2M_02':3.9, 
'B2_B2M_02':3.9, 'B2_B2M_02':3.9}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
cq={'A1_B2M_01':2.4, 'A2_B2M_01':5, 'A3_B2M_01':4, 'B1_B2M_02':3, 'B2_B2M_02':7, 'B3_B2M_02':6}

sums = dict()
for k, v in cq.iteritems():
    _, p2 = k.split('_', 1)
    if p2 not in sums:
        sums[p2] = [0, 0]
    sums[p2][0] += v
    sums[p2][1] += 1


res = {}
for k, v in sums.iteritems():
    res[k] = v[0]/float(v[1])

print res
```

also could be done with one iteration

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should work. You can probably make it a little more elegant.

```
cq = {'A1_B2M_01':2.04, 'A2_B2M_01':2.58, 'A3_B2M_01':2.80, 'B1_B2M_02':5.00, 'B2_B2M_02':4.30, 'B2_B2M_02':2.40 }
sum = {}
count = {}
mean = {}
for k in cq:
    if k[2:] in sum:
        sum[k[2:]] += cq[k]
        count[k[2:]] += 1
    else:
        sum[k[2:]] = cq[k]
        count[k[2:]] = 1
for k in sum:
    mean[k] = sum[k] / count[k]
```

Comment: This works and is going along what I was trying to write, thank you!

Comment: if the values are integers then the mean will give you an integer.
cast to float to be sure

Answer (score 0):

Grouping:

```
SEPARATOR = '_'
cq={'A1_B2M_01':2.4, 'A2_B2M_01':5, 'A3_B2M_01':4, 'B1_B2M_02':3, 'B2_B2M_02':7, 'B3_B2M_02':6}

groups = {}
for key in cq:
    group_key = SEPARATOR.join(key.split(SEPARATOR)[1:])
    if group_key in groups:
        groups[group_key].append(cq[key])
    else:
        groups[group_key] = [cq[key]]
```

Generate means:

```
def means(groups):
    for group, group_vals in groups.iteritems():
        yield (group, float(sum(group_vals)) / len(group_vals),)

print list(means(groups))
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work. I can't do the split'_' as the groups are characterised by B2M_0x, so if I split it I would get many more and not correct groups. Not sure why but I also got a Type Error trying to run your solution (    if group_key in groups:
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list')

Comment: @branwen85 I edited the solution. I did not understand your comment, are the groups determined by the string up to the first underscore?

Comment: Sorry, it's not very easy to explain! No, the groups are determined by the latter 2 parts. So, the groups are B2M_01 and B2M_02.